# Error building hyper ledger fabric docker image

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to build a hyper ledger fabric image, because here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/hsm.html they say:
"The prebuilt Hyperledger Fabric Docker images are not enabled to use PKCS11. If you are deploying Fabric using docker, you need to build your own images and enable PKCS11 using the following command:
make docker GO_TAGS=pkcs11"
There's no more information about it, so I supposed I had to get the docker file of an image and build it, i found the docker files here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/images/orderer/Dockerfile

First, I tried to build it without any modifications or custom paremeters to see if it works, but it doesnt, it shows:

```
docker build -t myimagehlf .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/22 : ARG GO_VER
Step 2/22 : ARG ALPINE_VER
Step 3/22 : FROM alpine:${ALPINE_VER} as base
invalid reference format
```

I think the error is on this line 'RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata', which is the fourth line of the docke file, but i have no idea why that's happening or how to fix it. I think the docker file from them should work so maybe I am doing the processs all wrong and there is another way to build "my own images". Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the intent here is to use git to clone the [Fabric GitHub repository](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric), then in your local copy of the repository (using the appropriate branch for the version of Fabric you are trying to build), to run the `make docker GO_TAGS=pkcs11` command. This target in the Fabric project's Makefile will build the Docker images.

Comment: thanks! if i used  GO_TAGS=pkcs11, it showed errors like 'bccsp/pkcs11/pkcs11.go:41:21: undefined: pkcs11.Ctx'... wihtout it, it built ok. Then i tried 'docker GO_TAGS=pkcs11' again, to enable pkcs11 bc they say "you need to build your own images and enable PKCS11 using the following command". That actually would enable it? it looks like it just ran some tests again...

Comment: That didnt enable it of course, i saw that images are create in the make file only once in the makefile. But i check out release 2.5 on git, on on that release worked well.

Comment: Looks like the main branch has been broken wrt to creating docker images and including HSM. I've raised an issue https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/issues/3645

Comment: @Samuel be aware that hyperledger fabric 2.5 has not been released yet, you should use a specific tag as well rather than a branch to match an official release

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the tag of the alpine image which is defined by variable `${ALPINE_VER}`
See all available tags:
https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/tags

`ARG ALPINE_VER=3.15`
which will pull `alpine:3.15`

I runned first line build

```bash
docker build -t test-image:0.1 --file Dockerfile .
[+] Building 23.5s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.2s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 225B                                       0.1s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.2s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.15             5.4s
 => [auth] library/alpine:pull token for registry-1.docker.io              0.0s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.15@sha256:69463fdff1f025c908939  0.4s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/alpine:3.15@sha256:69463fdff1f025c908939  0.1s
 => => sha256:69463fdff1f025c908939e86d4714b4d5518776954c 1.64kB / 1.64kB  0.0s
 => => sha256:7a38a4540724813e4190d086e955a8e757a7302551cc755 528B / 528B  0.0s
 => => sha256:c4fc938168588a0ba6178945c3d9047f27101eb3a42 1.47kB / 1.47kB  0.0s
 => [2/2] RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata                                   13.4s
 => exporting to image                                                     2.3s
 => => exporting layers                                                    2.2s
 => => writing image sha256:b707cc6dede25411607070e7560bd576a492c41ba9e88  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/test-image:0.1                          0.0s
```